# Workaround for deleting elements of shapefiles properly

Tags: qgis

I realise this is probably a long shot given the amount of discussion around this issue ([Deleted polygons seem to revert to older versions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169998/deleted-polygons-seem-to-revert-to-older-versions/170235#170235),["Phantom" features showing up in QGIS 2.4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123115/phantom-features-showing-up-in-qgis-2-4/123151#123151),[edits to attribute table in qgis do not show up in arcgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162615/edits-to-attribute-table-in-qgis-do-not-show-up-in-arcgis/162676#162676) ) but I wonder if anyone has found a workaround to get Qgis to delete shapefile elements properly (see bug 11007) http://hub.qgis.org/issues/11007 that does not involve saving the shapefile as a new layer. I have over 20 virtual fields attached to the layer in question and so 'save as' would cause me to have to re-write them all each time I edit.

Comment: You mention "the amount of discussion around this issue".  If any of that has been here at GIS SE, I think it would be helpful for you to include links to it within your question to save our volunteers having to go looking for it.

Comment: I've edited the question accordingly

Comment: I'm not sure what is you particular case. Are you editing dbf directly? are you using the result in in SAGA? Or in ArcGIS? Because I have never had any problem deleting shapefile features before.