# Shape without a layer

Tags: qgis

In QGIS I have a polygonal shape on the screen with an outline and fill
But no layers are visible
All layers are actually Hidden
The Identify Features doesn't recognise it

How to find where it is?
How can I remove it?

Comment: Hi Hui.., welcome to GIS.SE. Seems to be an invalid geometry (because Identify tool doesn't recognize it), but invalid geometries are prone to not being shown instead. In _Project > Properties > CRS_ tick on _No projection (...)_. QGIS will render without projectig the layers on the fly to the project CRS. Layers will be shown in their native coordinates. Can you see the polygon there? Make visible one to one the layers and _Zoom to Layer_ . Please, [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/310538/edit) to add what version of QGIS you use .

Comment: Try turning it off and on again?

Comment: As jberrio said, just restart QGIS (maybe more than once?). Did you have this layer turned on at some point?  Sometimes it happens, legacy objects don't get cleared.

Comment: Potentially related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123115/phantom-features-showing-up-in-qgis